# How to display child(Grand Child or any level of child) component to look as its top most parent's sibling in the same grid

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, slds, sfdc-styleguide

I do want to have UI something like the image attached bellow:

[image: Expected UI]

But finding the code is not creating such. Instead getting UI as shown in bellow attached image:

[image]

What I'm doing wrong. Find the code(HTML & JS) of parent and child component within the project link attached bellow.

https://webcomponents.dev/edit/oDMNHt8i25IAWJd2mLar/src/app.html

FYI: As of now I am passing hardcoded width style to the child but it would be dynamically calculated as 1-of-4 of the grid's width.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would "flatten" your parent-child tree into an array : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453824/flatten-hierarchical-data, then I would apply flexbox **to all the elements** to show them https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I do not agree with Denis as there are lots of use cases where we may not want to change the existing data structure because of certain reasons. Well in that case you may want to have a look at the recently introduced [contents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property. This surely is available to fulfill this kind of purpose.

You only have to add `display: contents` property to the elements that are the parent of the child you wanted as sibling until the parent you want as a sibling.
This also affects the DOM accessibility structure.

I also forked your repo & is available [here](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/GT0GuVtqMKXYDqaqaQsj).
Notice

```
c-child {
    display: contents;
}
```

in the app.css.

If you have the same kind of structure in your lwc compo you can directly put

```
:host {
    display: contents;
}
```

in you child component css file & it will appear the same as you wanted.
You may want to read more about display contents [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) & [here](https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents).

Comment: thanks, Sachin. But our requirement has changed a bit. Added a unique presidency property in each child object having its values in the range of [A001 - Z999]. Now we need to display children according to their presidency as well. For eg, if the deepest child will have presidency of 'A001' it will be displayed first then any other p tag even though the child's p tag is rendered at last.